# How to define a schema directive with GraphQLObjectType

Tags: graphql-js

With `grapgql-js`, I can define directives on schema:

```
type MyObj implements MyInterface @onObject {
    myField(myArg: Int @onArgumentDefinition): String @onFieldDefinition
}
```

I can parse this with `buildSchema`, but how I can define this kind of metadata with `GraphQLObjectType`?

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can't.
There are some discussions going on about including this sort of metadata but I don't think it will happen.
looking at discussions [here](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/1262)

> Right now directives are purely a feature of the GraphQL language and IDL, so a schema not created using IDL definitionally won't contain directives. When building a schema in code, you have the full power of the host programming environment, so directives shouldn't be necessary. Directives are a tool for supplying additional intent to be later interpreted by the host programming environment.

There are more issues and PR's around that if you follow the links.